# how to make a field of the class to be of the same type as parameter in constructor

Tags: python

I'm a fully "static typed" man and a beginner in python and I want to make a datatype in python, which saves prev-next states of some objects. The structure is like this:

```
class PrevCurr:
    def __init__(self, obj_initial):
       self.previous = obj_initial
       self.current = obj_initial
```

No problem if my `obj_initial` is something like `[None, None]` or so. But imagine I need to wrap this class onto the different big types, like dictionaries/lists/sets of 1000+ elements or/and user-defined classes. Then I would like to have something like this:

```
class PrevCurr:
    def __init__(self, obj_type, *args, **kwargs):
       '''make self.previous and self.orientation of the same type as obj_type'''
       self.previous = ...
       self.current = ...
```

My question is: how to be sure, that fields (or is there another name in python for them?) are set to be of the same type as the object, onto which I want to wrap? I have the idea presented above, that I may somehow to pass the type and additional info about that, like size and etc. as parameters instead of object itself to save the memory, but how then to ensure, that my fields are set to be exactly the same type as the object? afaik I cannot pass constructors as parameters in python and I couldn't find any sort of generic programming in python for that task. Or I got the idea fully wrong.

Comment: This isn't going to work - you want to be able to save snapshots of object states, but there is no general mechanism to do that in Python. The closest thing is `copy.deepcopy`, which is flaky and limited. This isn't like C++ with copy constructors and copy assignment.

Comment: Also, it's not clear why you thought your initial approach would work for `[None, None]` but not for larger data structures.

Comment: Why not? If I have an update method or so, which rewrite the instance's previous with the current, and current with input, it seems okay for me in any language

Comment: [Here's an example](https://ideone.com/j1GGPG) of a naive attempt failing to save the previous state.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica the problem is in `append`, which affects all the references, if you reassign list each time, it works https://ideone.com/6gS2zV
For big-size lists, where reassignment costs, I'm not sure, maybe some also some wrapper onto appending, so that it affects only desired member variable.

Comment: Fundamentally, you want to save object states, but you're really saving object references, so anything that actually changes an object's state will expose the problem.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica that's exactly the reason, why do I need such external wrapper and couldn't do this directly into the class, where the main stuff proceeds. Since I'm operating with the list of sensors' data, it's not a big problem to reassign it during each refreshment period with a new data and check the difference between two last "snapshots" through the wrapper. You're totally right about more complicated "working structures" than small lists, then there is certainly a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're thinking as you would in a static-typed language like C or Java, where you have to pre-allocate memory for objects of a specific type before assigning anything to them. This is the wrong approach in python.

Instead, let's consider what you *want*: a class that can represent any single type, but which, once initialized, can *only* represent that particular type. In Java, you would use a generic for this, but python doesn't have those. What we *can* do in python is to make sure that only objects of the correct type can be assigned to it.

The idiomatic way of doing something like this in python is throwing an error at runtime if the programmer uses the class incorrectly; there's not really a good way for a static typechecker to throw a compile-time error, like it might in Java. I present the following for your consideration:

```
class PrevCurr:
    @property
    def previous(self):
        return self._previous
    @previous.setter
    def previous(self, value):
        if not isinstance(value, self._type):
            raise ValueError(f"Previous value must be of type {self._type}")
        self._previous = value

    @property
    def current(self):
        return self._current
    @current.setter
    def current(self, value):
        if not isinstance(value, self._type):
            raise ValueError(f"Current value must be of type {self._type}")
        self._current = value

    def __init__(self, obj_initial):
        self._type = type(obj_initial)
        self._previous = obj_initial
        self._current = obj_initial
```

Here, we have two external-facing variables: `previous` and `current`, as you have in your current example. Because we want specific behaviors on *setting* these variables, we use the `@property` decorator to declare them. Their actual values are held in the 'private' variables `_previous` and `_current`, respectively.

Upon initialization, we check the type of the initial object, and *store that type to the class* as the 'private' variable `_type`.

Then, each time something (even the class's instance itself) tries to set `instance.previous` or `instance.current`, we redirect it to the appropriate function. In this function, we check whether the object to be set is the same type as what we initialized the class with. If not, we throw an error.

---

If you're storing, for example, a list or other collection, then I don't think there's any reasonable way to ensure that the entire list remains the same type (or, indeed, to make any assumption about the *contents* of the list, since python itself doesn't. They're all `<type 'list'>`).

One possible workaround would be to use metaclasses and [overriding the `__instancecheck__()` metaclass method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-instance-and-subclass-checks), to create a subclass of `dict` that only holds a specific type of object, and then initialize your `PrevCurr` instance with one of those.

I presume from the name of the class that you have some method `.update()` that copies over the `current` value to `previous`, and assigns a new `current` value that must be the same type. In that case you might want to play around with the getters and setters to make assigning directly to `previous` harder.

---

Example of usage:

```
>>> a = PrevCurr(3)
>>> a.previous = 2
>>> a.previous = 4.5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 8, in previous
ValueError: Previous value must be of type <class 'int'>
```

Comment: wrong, `Dict[str,MyCustomObj]` object type will obviously sneak, as `type(X)` will return only `dict`

Comment: well, at least it will work with a basic types, but complex or templates ....not

Comment: @Reishin As I say in my disclaimer, "If you're storing, for example, a list or other collection, then I don't think there's any reasonable way to ensure that the entire list remains the same type". I don't know of any good way to accomplish that in python, as all collections are generic and type hints aren't compiled. That said, I just thought of a possible workaround using metaclasses and have added that to my answer.

Comment: You presumed absolutely correct about the `update` method, that's the rough idea. I need this for doing the measurements of the robot's traveled distance, while having constantly updated positions in space through sensors. Yeah, actually I don't have user-defined types there, or big-size collections, I interested only in theory. Your approach is certainly new for me, looks hard and dangerous esp. in the part about runtime exceptions but very interesting. It doesn't work for me as wanted though with smth. like `[MyType1, MyType2]`, but still that's very interesting, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: stop...then the task is kinda simple, @gehirndienst need an ordered List with strict type checking?

Comment: @gehirndienst the approach used called `properties`, it is like getters and setters in java, the way in python to control the access to the "private" fields

Comment: @Reishin, it's not a ordered or linked list, it's only a wrapper which allows to do measurements between two last sensor outputs in real time apps. I was interested however, if that approach could be expanded to the arbitrary types.

In Java there is no such problem since you have to declare the type of the parameter(s)

Comment: @gehirndienst here you could use `type annotations`, they could help you check typing. However, for this you need to use linter as python is not strict-type language. Or IDE will lint it for you.